# How to connect to RSK node over websockets?

Tags: websocket, rsk

I'm trying to connect to my RSK node via a websocket:

```sh
wscat -c ws://localhost:4445/websocket
```

However, I get this result: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4445`.

The docs say that websocket listens to port `4445` by default.

How do I connect correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Websockets are disabled by default.
See [RSKj configuration reference](https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/blob/master/rskj-core/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L266)

To enable websockets on RSKj:
(1)
Add `-Drpc.providers.web.ws.enabled=true` to your `java` command when starting RSKj.
(2)
Update the configuration file.
The file is named `mainnet.conf` for RSK Mainnet.

- See [RSKj node configuration](https://developers.rsk.co/rsk/node/configure/)
  for how to locate and edit the config file.
- See [RPC protocol configuration reference](https://developers.rsk.co/rsk/node/configure/reference/#rpc)  for a detailed explanation about the various RPC configurations available, including the ones related to websockets.

Your config file should look like this:

```json
rpc {
providers : {
    web: {
        cors: "*",
        http: {
            enabled: true,
            bind_address = "0.0.0.0",
            hosts = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"],
            port: 4444,
            }
        ws: {
            enabled: true,
            bind_address: "127.0.0.1",
            hosts = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"],
            port: 4445,
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

After this, restart your RSKj for the config to take effect.
Now if you repeat the same command from your question:

```sh
wscat -c ws://localhost:4445/websocket
```

You should be able to establish a connection.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to connect in a correct way.

However, make sure that you have a right to connect to this port,

For example,

```
rpc.providers.web.ws.bind_address=127.0.0.1
```

or

```
rpc.providers.web.ws.bind_address=0.0.0.0
```

2. You have to specify that Websockets are on `rpc.providers.web.ws.enabled=true`